# How do you specify image URLs in tvOs that include ampersands?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv

I have the following image tag in an TVXML file:

```
<img src="http://dqndusk8a84ol.cloudfront.net/image/a2e92e83778e3fdaf05f88cffbee1c7e.jpg?&amp;x=720&amp;y=427&amp;icq=50&amp;sig=934b011bc0039797f64e9d268dfbc859" width="720" height="427"/>
```

The emulator does not seem to want to load this image. It has the placeholder image shown (basically a gray background) but not my image.

I've tried double encoding the ampersand as well has just having the bare & but no dice.

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Versions: XCode 7.1 Beta 3, tvOS Beta 3

Update: I've opened a radar ticket with id: 23149717.

Comment: I'm seeing this too, and the related existing encoding posts all wind up with `&amp;` for the ampersands which isn't working.

Comment: Did you try not 'encoding' the ampersands at all, and just using ampersands (that is, replace your `&amp;`s with `&`s)?

Comment: @ScottHunter Yeah, unfortunately, that doesn't work and was the first thing I tried. I get this error message: `2015-10-16 13:41:43.656 WSLAppleTvTest[2802:131504] ITML <Error>: Error Domain=ITMLKitErrorDomain Code=200 "Entity: line 15: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';'
/dqndusk8a84ol.cloudfront.net/image/a2e92e83778e3fdaf05f88cffbee1c7e.jpg?x=720&y`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no real problem here. This URL looks to have needed a extra ampersand to work (guessing the signature param in this URL took that prepended ampersand into account).

Answer (score 0):

Nice, I just filed a radar as well: 23531029

FWIW, I was able to get it to work by replacing "&" in the url with "&"
(found from this blog: http://mrcoles.com/blog/how-use-amersands-html-encode/)

I took your exact block of html above (copy and paste) and it worked for me..